# How to identify cells with HARDCODED numbers added to a formula in the same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a column, there is a formula calculating incentives as **Sales Column * Bonus %** column. But some cells also had a manual addition of hardcoded values to the formula resulting in increase of incentive.

How can we find any such manual additions to the formula without using helper columns.

Please suggest any dynamic array formula or Conditional formatting. Remember the hardcoded values are added to formula, so you can't identify it with Ctrl G > Formulas.

Comment: *How can we find any such manual additions to the formula without using helper columns* Without helper columns at all I think your only option would be VBA. But you can use a temporary helper column. Just add a helper column with formula `Sales Column * Bonus % column` and check if that output is equal to original one. If it's not means that row got a hardcoded value in formula. Then delete helper column

Comment: May be something like this would work: `=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(C2),{"*","+"}), FILTER(x, 1-ISERR(--x),"Not Hardcoded"))` i am just guessing based on the OP. a markdown data may would have helped. Or to spill `=MAP(C2:C7,LAMBDA(y, LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(y),{"*","+"}), FILTER(x, 1-ISERR(--x),"Not Hardcoded"))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an example and assumption based on the OP posted, it can be amended:

[image]

---

```
=MAP(C2:C7,LAMBDA(y, 
 LET(x, --TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(y),{"*","+"}), 
 FILTER(x, 1-ISERR(x),"Not Hardcoded"))))
```

---

- Using `MAP()` function to map each value in the array, and pass a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to get the desired output.
- Using `TEXTSPLIT()` to split by columns using the delimiters, while `FORMULATEXT()` function returns the formulas as text.
- Next, using converting the returned array to check whether it is a number or alphanumeric( this is because the formula is referencing two columns **Sales** & **Bonus%**), if its Text returns error while number returns the number as is.
- Using `1-ISERR()` which works same as `ISNUMBER()` to get `TRUE` and `FALSE` for a number and false for error.
- Wrapping within `FILTER()` to get the output based on the `TRUE`s found above.

---

Comment: Great Mayukh. Thanks. COntinuing with your example, Is there any way to do the same if  my incentive calculation is A2*6% and I want to know if the incentive column has any hard coded adddition (For eg: A78*6% + 2300).

Comment: You mean to say the `6%` as well as `2300`?

Comment: Try: `=MAP(C2:C8,LAMBDA(y, LET(x, --TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(y),{"*","+"}), CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(x, 1-ISERR(x),"Not Hardcoded"),-1))))`